# Enabling multiple security managers in a single java thread

Tags: java, security

Suppose there's a java thread, where classes get loaded which are provided by multiple parties. Can those providers specify their own security managers and policies s.t. they can restrict the access among those providers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one `SecurityManager` set as the security manager.

Threads have little to do with security in Java. Objects are passed between threads, so it doesn't make much sense to use a thread-based access model.

In Java each class gets assigned a `ProtectionDomain` and hence a set of permissions (these might be in some sense "dynamic" but for most purposes it's effectively constant). When the security manager is asked to check a permission, it delegates to the `AccessController` which checks each `ProtectionDomain` active on the stack (roughly). In practice you need to isolate code from multiple parties, but each party can have its own `ProtectionDomain` and hence permissions.

Comment: @erickson Yeah, but the only important method in `ProtectionDomain` is `implies`. If you want to know whether a `ProtectionDomain` should allow a permission, call that method instead of trying to get properties and doing some distinctly non-OO (and wrong) code.